# Can I restore metadata wiped out by Topaz using Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, metadata, troubleshooting, lightroom-4

When using Lightroom, I edit a photo in Topaz Adjust. When the edited photo is imported back into Lightroom, some of the metadata is missing - namely the focal length, ISO, shutter speed, and aperture. I notice these things because they leave a big gap in the Loupe info, which makes me think that other data may also have gone missing.

Is there a way I can use Lightroom to restore this data to the edited image?

Comment: what Topaz version you're using?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Fusion to get to Adjust, you should be returning a copy of the image to Lightroom, so the original image should still be available in the stack to copy and paste the metadata from. Fusion is a very basic plugin host/editor, and while it's a workaround for Lightroom, it's actually intended for people who don't have any sort of an image editor installed (point-and-shoot types).

Note that Topaz is releasing a new product (should be this week or next), **photoFXlab**, that is more Lightroom-friendly. The release price is $29; the retail price after release will be higher ($79, IIRC). I've only seen the sneak peek, but it's supposed to act like a LR plug-in from Lightroom rather than as an "edit in" option, and provides a layering/masking environment while the image is in the plugin. It will still work as a stand-alone, as Fusion does, but as far as I've been able to determine it's supposed to work directly from LR as well.

ADDED: After a glitch in the 1.0 version forced a hold (a new product registration system left some users unable to use the software), photoFXlab 1.1 has been released (today — June 29, 2012) with the old product key registration system, the "social" features removed, some genuine UI improvements, and I can confirm that it maintains metadata when round-tripping from Lightroom. The $29 launch price has been extended to July 31, 2012. (I must really be starting to sound like a shill, but I've been bugging the good folks at Topaz about this for a while, and I'm kind of impressed with the improvements they made while fixing the registration system. It feels like more than a dot release compared to 1.0.)

Comment: I'm keeping my eye on photoFXlab. Thanks, @StanRogers.

Answer (score 0):

One way around would be to backup metadata using [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) and then recover them after processing. The backup can be made to XMP or to more elaborate MIE format.

There are also GUI tools for metadata backup.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is "yes" and [Syncomatic](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&loc=en_us&extid=2309524) might be the tool to do it.